# How to modify the z depth value inside the vertex function of a surface shader?

Tags: unity, hlsl, depth-buffer, surface-shader

I wrote the following surface shader.
The idea is to increase the Z depth value of vertices, after projection.

```
Shader "Custom/Highlighted"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Lambert
        #pragma vertex vert 

        struct Input
        {
            float4 pos: SV_POSITION;
            float4 color : COLOR;           
        };
        
        void vert(inout appdata_full v, out Input o) 
        {
            UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input, o);       //
            o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex); // does not work
            o.pos.z += 0.001;                        //
            o.color = v.color;                       //
        }

        fixed4 _Color;
        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
        {
            o.Albedo = _Color.rgb;
            o.Alpha = _Color.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

The shader compiles, and objects are rendered correctly, however it's like the z depth value is not modified at all (what is inside vert is ineffective).

Here is the equivalent code as a fragment shader (which work perfectly) :

```
struct vertInput {
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR0;
    float4 uv : TEXCOORD1;
};

struct vertOutput {
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    fixed4 color : COLOR0;
};

vertOutput vert (vertInput input)
{
    vertOutput o;
    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, input.pos);
    o.pos.z += 0.001;
    o.color = input.color;
    return o;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write to `v.vertex`, which is the vertex position that gets used for projection and depth testing?

Comment: AFAIK `v.vertex` is before projection, I would like to modify the properties after projection (at that moment, z property should be what is written to depth buffer)

Comment: So, transform it to post-projection space, modify it, then transform it back to continue down the pipeline. I've done this in a previous answer.

Comment: I see what you mean, that's a little weird but it should work. Btw you have 2500+ answers, can you add a link to the one I can use as reference ?

Comment: [Only four that use custom vertex functions in a Surface Shader](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A39518++vertex%3Avert), so that narrows down your search space. [Here's one that shows transforming into view space, modifying, and transforming back](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/184840/39518) — you can extend that to go all the way into post-projection space. If you just want a depth bias though, [there are built in methods for that](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html) (see the "Offset" section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by DMGregory, one solution to apply depth bias is to use the [Offset](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Offset.html) keyword :

```
Shader "Custom/Highlighted"
{
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        Offset 0, -1 //pulls the polygon closer to the camera
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Another way is to transform vertex into view space, modify it as wanted, then transform back, as explained [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/184839/how-to-perform-some-custom-math-between-the-model-matrix-and-the-projection-matr/184840#184840).