# Shirt in front of body: Render a gameobject always in front of another despite position, keep lighting

Tags: unity, shaders

How do you "hide" the body behind a shirt, or render the shirt as always in front of the body - without losing the lighting?

Comment: [It looks to me like you've already asked this question and received answers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/188675/39518). The techniques described there work with lighting too - you'd just need to write your own lit shader following the guidance there, or pay a developer to write one for you if you're uncomfortable with shader development. If you're unsatisfied with the answers on your original question, you can always edit your question to re-focus it on what you need.

Comment: was hoping for a new / different solution that did not require a custom texture mask for clothing. maybe something more elegant like a clothing shader that would always be in front of the skin shader.

Comment: I provided an option that sid not include a custom texture mask. [You can also see recent Q&A on depth biasing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/199000/39518) if that's all you need.

Comment: Well, your solution actually includes something more burdensome than the custom texture mask - vertex allocation or something. For depth biasing, can it be set to within a small radius, so that the chest part of a shirt does not cover the lower arms in case the lower arms are in front for example?

Comment: 1) If you consider vertex attributes to be burdensome, I have bad news for you about the rest of gamedev. 2) Did you consider... trying it to find out for yourself? 